# Function to return a value from array based on input

Tags: javascript

I have an array with values

```
const range = [1,10,100,500,1000,2000,4000,8000]

let input = 1580
```

The expected output is 1000 because 1580 is between 1000 and 2000

But my code is giving wrong results and also giving incorrect for large values.

```
for(i=0;i<range.length;i++)
{
    if(input > range[i]) 
        break;
}
console.log(range[i])
```

Comment: Variables should be declared with `const` or `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const range = [1,10,100,500,1000,2000,4000,8000]

let input = 1580

console.log(range.reduce((a,c)=>c<=input?c:a))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare `input < range` to find the first one that's larger than the `input`.

Then, if you can expect the array to be sorted, you'd need to use the value *before* the index at which you break, because that's after the limit has been exceeded.

```js
const range = [1, 10, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000]
const input = 1580
let i;
for (i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
  if (input < range[i])
    break;
}
console.log(i);
console.log(range[i - 1])
```

But a better approach that doesn't depend on the array being sorted would be to `.reduce` to keep the largest number found so far fulfilling the condition as the accumulator.

```js
const range = [1,1560,10,100,500,1000,1500,2000,4000,8000,1550];
const input = 1580;
const output = range.reduce(
  (bestSoFar, num) => num > input ? bestSoFar : Math.max(bestSoFar, num),
  0
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Reduce also depends on the order. If the range array is not sorted, reduce will just give you the last number that is > input.
Test it with [1,1560,10,100,500,1000,1500,2000,4000,8000,1550], and it will give you 1550 and not 1560.

Comment: Oops, you're right, need a `Math.max`

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=0;i<range.length;i++)
{
    if(input > range[i]) 
        break;
}
console.log(range[i]);
```

On line no:3 , the boolean condition is wrong, what you are effectively trying to do is check whether the input is greater than the each value of range.

Your loop will break itself on the first value of the range array, (ie. range[0]) , thus you won't get the desired output.

You need to tweek the code a little bit.